# How to merge two dataframes so that rows contain elements that start with an element in a column to the left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two dataframes, or maybe two dataframe columns:

```
  val
0 '1_1'
1 '2_2'
2 '2_1'
3 '3_1'
4 '3_2'
5 '3_3'
```

and

```
  val
0 '1_1'
1 '1_2'
2 '2_2'
3 '2_1'
4 '3_1'
5 '4_1'
```

What is the best way to reach this desired result:

```
  val1 val2
0 '1_1' '1_1'
1 '1_2'   
2 '2_1' '2_1'
3 '2_2' '2_2'
4 '3_1' '3_1'
5       '3_2'
6       '3_3'
7 '4_1'
```

I have tried turning the dataframes into lists and running the following:

```
text = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x.startswith(y.split('_')[0]):
            text.append([x,y])
df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns = ['val1', 'val2'])
```

But there are so many duplicates and trying to get rid of the duplicates gets rid of the order I'm seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces your sample output. I'm not sure though that it solves your general problem...

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(["1_1", "2_2", "2_1", "3_1", "3_2", "3_3"], name="s1")
s2 = pd.Series(["1_1", "1_2", "2_2", "2_1", "3_1", "4_1"], name="s2")

joint = pd.merge(s2, s1, left_on="s2", right_on="s1", how='outer')
joint["sort_order"] = joint["s2"].str[0].fillna(joint["s1"].str[0])
joint = joint.sort_values(by=["sort_order", "s2", "s1"]).fillna("")
print(joint)
```

Result:

```
    s2   s1 sort_order
0  1_1  1_1          1
1  1_2               1
3  2_1  2_1          2
2  2_2  2_2          2
4  3_1  3_1          3
6       3_2          3
7       3_3          3
5  4_1               4
```

Explanation: Join the two lists with `how='outer'` to get all the values from both lists, then sort according to first letter from first column if it exists, otherwise from first letter of second column.

Comment: The "joint" dataframe I'm getting has no overlap between the two columns... I'm not exactly working with the data in my sample problem but it does follow the same formula where there's a bunch of numbers separated by underscores. Can you think of a reason this might be?

Comment: @ACan Sorry, that's hard to say without further information. Maybe you have no overlapping column names or there are actually no identical values between the two columns. Can you post sample data from your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as far as the ordering your after, the better way would be to create numerical type columns and sort them. But as far as the merge, here's a cool trick I just learned:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='A'.split('_')[0])
```

**Example:**

```
>>> df1
     A
0  1_1
1  2_1
2  5_1
>>> df2
     A      C
0  1_1   some
1  2_1  extra
2  6_1   data
>>> df3 = df.merge(df2,how='left',on='A'.split('_')[0])
     A      C
0  1_1   some
1  2_1  extra
2  5_1    NaN
```

Comment: This was exciting, but didn't really help with my example.How do you create numerical type columns? is it like the sort order of the above example?